# I can't collect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nan, addition

I'm new to `javascript`, I want to place a code in my `html` page like the following, but I get a `NaN` error or no error. He just doesn't make the sums. My `html` page is in Turkish but I hope you will understand. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help
in two different `tables`

```
<td id="Hizmet_Bedeli1">35</td>
<td id="Hizmet_Bedeli2">35</td>
```

it needs to show a total in another `table`

```
<th scope="row" class="align-middle" id="Ham_Toplam"> </th>
```

Here is the `javascript`:

```
{
var hb1= document.getElementById("Hizmet_Bedeli1").textContent; // If I use .value also, it doesn't work if I use .textContent as well.
var hb2= document.getElementById("Hizmet_Bedeli2").textContent; // .value de kullansam .textContent de kullansam düzelmiyor

var hizmet_toplam= parseInt(hb1) + parseInt(hb2); //parseInt de kullansam Number de kullansam Nan hatasıalıyorum... // If I use parseInt with Number, I get Nan error ...

document.getElementById("Ham_Toplam").innerHTML = hizmet_toplam;
    
}
```

I want to add the textContent of `#Hizmet_Bedeli1` and `#Hizmet_Bedeli2` together.

Comment: Please remember that Java is not Javascript and to format your code properly

Comment: Try `innerHtml` instead of textContent

Comment: Do you know how to check the console? Bring it up by pressing F12. I suggest that you add `console.log(hb1, hb2)` to the code (before the `hizmet_toplam` declaration), and then check in the console if both or any of the values are correct.

Comment: Hello Rickart, this information was helpful for me. I'm getting an error with something. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Answer (score 3):

You are most probably not wrapping your `tr` and `th` tags in a `table` tag, which will cause your browser to not render the elements.

```js
{
  var hb1 = document.getElementById("Hizmet_Bedeli1").textContent;
  var hb2 = document.getElementById("Hizmet_Bedeli2").textContent;
  var hizmet_toplam = parseInt(hb1) + parseInt(hb2);
  document.getElementById("Ham_Toplam").innerHTML = hizmet_toplam;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id="Hizmet_Bedeli1">35</td>
<td id="Hizmet_Bedeli2">35</td>
<tr/>
<th scope="row" class="align-middle" id="Ham_Toplam"> </th>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick reply. Since my tables contain different things, if I add them to the same table, everything gets mixed up. Isn't there any other method? They have to not be under different TR's

Comment: @EmrahGüler Use some other tag, like `p` or `div`